# How can I set the transparency/opacity and color of a shape in google slides using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I am trying to set the colour of a shape on google slides using AppsScript. I am able to achieve this but realise that transparency values are 0.  How can I set a new colour and the transparency value? I have tried to add transparency direct to the hex i.e. #F2E4002B for 95% Transparency - but this fails.

```
function colourForeground(aShape) {

let aColour = "#E4002B"

  aShape.getText().getTextStyle().setForegroundColor(aColour);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use [setSolidFill(hexString,alpha)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/fill#setsolidfillhexstring,-alpha) to set both the color and the opacity of the shape.**

In the following example, we set **hexString** to `#E4002B` and **alpha** to 95% or `0.95`:

```
function colourForeground(aShape) {

let aColour = "#E4002B";
aShape.getFill().setSolidFill(aColour,0.95);

}
```

The second argument of this function (**alpha**) controls the opacity and takes values between `0` and `1`.